# Binary search for a failing line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, search, split

`git` has `bisect run` to figure out which revision an error was introduced.

I have a big file (100GB) and at least one of the lines is bad, but the program I have to check it with will not tell me which line.

The lines are records, so I can write a binary search using `head` and `tail` and `/2` (passing the first half to the program, and if no errors, the second half), and based on that splitting the one half again.

But does an automated tool already exist that can do this without my intervention (similar to `git bisect run`)?

Comment: What kind of file?  Source code?  Plain text?

Comment: Plain text: Each line is a full record.

Comment: I suggest looking into [git-bisect.sh from git repository](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a907786af835ac15962be53f1492f23e044f479/git-bisect.sh) instead and modifying the code to suit your need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `split` to split a file into multiple parts, and it has an option to only split at lines:

```
$ ls
bigfile
$ split -n l/2 bigfile
$ ls
bigfile xaa xab
```

this really only makes sense if the file *can* be split and is organized in lines, which is only true for textfiles.

with this you can easily build your own bisect-tool, e.g. something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

TESTPROG=$1
DATA=$2

usage() {
    echo "usage: $0 <testprog> <datafile>"
    echo "     will bisect <datafile> to the single line where <testprog> exits with '0'"
    exit 1
}

if [ ! -x "${TESTPROG}" ]; then  usage; fi
if [ ! -e "${DATA}" ]    ; then  usage; fi

BISECTDIR=$(mktemp -d)

splitfiles() {
    split -e -n l/2 $1 ${BISECTDIR}/$2bisect_
    echo ${BISECTDIR}/$2bisect_*
}
cleanup() {
    rm -rf "${BISECTDIR}"
    exit 0
}

i=1
while [ $(head -2 "${DATA}" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; do
  echo "testing: ${DATA} $(head -2 "${DATA}" | wc -l)" 1>&2
  files=$(splitfiles ${DATA} ${i})
  count=$(echo $files | awk '{print NF}')
  if [  ${count} -lt 2 ]; then
      cat $files
      cleanup
  fi
  DATA=""
  for f in $files; do
          if ${TESTPROG} "${f}" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
          DATA="${f}"
          break
      fi
  done
  i=$(( i+1 ))
done

cleanup
```

caveat: this will put all the bisected data into `/tmp` (change the definition of BISECTDIR is you don't like that); also this will only cleanup the bisected data files at the end. so you might need plenty of space...

Comment: What I am looking for is a bigger tool - similar to 'git bisect run' that will do the splitting and testing without my intervention.

Comment: @OleTange i've updated my answer to include such a tool written in bash.

Answer (score 0):

https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/find-first-fail

```
find-first-fail -f 100g.file -v myprogram
```

It will identify lines X..Y where `myprogram` fails. It does that with 2 binary searches: First it keeps X=1 and searches for Y, so it finds the minimal Y where `myprogram` fails for 1..Y. Then it keeps Y and searches for X, thus finding X..Y where `myprogram` fails.

If there are multiple sections where `myprogram` fails, it will only identify one of them.

Comment: *`. $(which find-first-fail)`* should be `. find-first-fail` in [POSIX shells whose `.`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) is require to look for /-less files in `$PATH`. `which` is very unportable. You may want to use `command -v` instead, but like most `which` implementations, that only finds executable files. In any case leaving that command substitution unquoted doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just finished a [generic bisect tool](https://gitlab.com/engmark/bisect), written in Bash and thoroughly tested. The code right now:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail
shopt -s failglob inherit_errexit

next_file="$2"
entries_checked=0

cleanup() {
    if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 0)); then
        printf 'Number of entries checked: %d.\n' "$entries_checked" >&2
    fi
    rm --force --recursive "$work_dir"
}
work_dir="$(mktemp --directory)"
trap cleanup EXIT

while true; do
    ((++entries_checked))
    if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 0)); then
        printf 'Remaining entry count: %d.\n' "$(wc --lines < "$next_file")" >&2
    fi
    split_prefix="${work_dir}/${entries_checked}-"
    split --elide-empty-files --number=l/2 "$next_file" "$split_prefix"
    split_files=("$split_prefix"*)
    if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 1)); then
        printf 'First split file entry count: %d.\n' "$(wc --lines < "${split_files[0]}")" >&2
    fi
    if [[ -v split_files[1] ]]; then
        if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 1)); then
            printf 'Second split file entry count: %d.\n' "$(wc --lines < "${split_files[1]}")" >&2
        fi
    fi

    entry="$(tail --lines=1 "${split_files[0]}")"
    if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 1)); then
        printf 'Checking entry: “%s”.\n' "$entry" >&2
    fi

    if ENTRY="$entry" "$SHELL" <<< "$1"; then
        if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 1)); then
            printf 'Command successful.\n' >&2
        fi

        rm "${split_files[0]}"

        if ! [[ -v split_files[1] ]]; then
            echo 'No insertion point found.' >&2
            exit 3
        fi
        next_file="${split_files[1]}"
    else
        if (("${DEBUG-0}" > 1)); then
            printf 'Command failed.\n' >&2
        fi

        first_bad_entry="$entry"

        if [[ -v split_files[1] ]]; then
            rm "${split_files[1]}"
        fi
        next_file="${split_files[0]}"
        if (("$(head --lines=2 "$next_file" | wc --lines)" == 1)); then
            printf '%s\n' "$first_bad_entry"
            exit
        fi
    fi
done
```